# Remove duplicated items in one list and add items with same index position in second list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists x and y and each item in x is pointing to corresponding position in y

```
x = [1,2,3,4,2,3]
y = [30, 40, 10, 80, 100,40]
```

I want to get as:

```
x=[1,2,3,4]  
y=[30,140,50,80]
```

Overall, remove duplicated items in x and add items in y with corresponding index positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A super basic approach could be using a good old loop:

```
res = {}
for i1, i2 in zip(x, y):
    res[i1] = res.get(i1, 0) + i2 # if i1 not in res, will default to 0

x = list(res.keys())
y = [res[i] for i in x]
```

Comment: There're very rare cases when you need to use `dict.keys()`, in 99,99% you shouldn't do it as it will just consume memory. Use `x = list(res)`. Also last list comprehension could be replaced with `y = list(res.values())`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you create a `dict` where the key is the value from `x` and the value is sum of values from `y` using index from `x`

Then zip to passe from pairs `[(1, 30), (2, 140), (3, 50), (4, 80)]` back to `x,y` lists

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3]
y = [30, 40, 10, 80, 100, 40]

results = defaultdict(int)
for i, vx in enumerate(x):
    results[vx] += y[i]
print(results)  # {1: 30, 2: 140, 3: 50, 4: 80}

new_x, new_y = zip(*results.items())
print(new_x)  # (1, 2, 3, 4)
print(new_y)  # (30, 140, 50, 80)
```

Comment: You can use `[*x], [*y] = zip(*d.items())` as alternative to get result in lists.

Comment: @azro, It's working for me, thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Creating a dictionary to approach this problem will be easier-

```
d = dict()
for i in range(len(x)):
    if x[i] in d:
        d[x[i]] += y[i]
    else:
        d[x[i]] = y[i]

print(d)
```

Once you create the dictionary '`d`' with desired result, you can create new `x, y` lists by obtaining the keys and values of that dictionary using `list()` command-

```
x, y = list(d) , list(d.values())

print(x)
print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

Just creates a new list of zeroes, whose length is based on the difference between length of list x and length of set of list x, and add the value of y to the value in the corresponding index (from the x list) into the res list

```py
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3]
y = [30, 40, 10, 80, 100,40]

res = [0]*len(set(x))

for i, j in enumerate(x):
    res[j-1] += y[i]

print(res)
```

Output:

```py
[30, 140, 50, 80]
```

Tell me if its not working...